# Tengo el siguiente error en SQL 1418 Y 2014

Tags: mysql, sql, funciones, mysql-workbench

Soy nuevo en SQL y estoy programando unas funciones siguiendo una guía de un profesor, sin embargo tengo el siguiente script:

```
USE MODERN_FAMILY;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS comparar_numeros; 
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION comparar_numeros(n INT, m INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
BEGIN
DECLARE s VARCHAR(20);
IF n>m THEN SET s=">"; 
ELSEIF n=m 
THEN SET s="="; 
ELSE SET s="<";
END IF;
SET s = CONCAT(n," ", s, " ",m);
RETURN s; 
END;$$
;
```

Cuando lo ejecuto me sale este error:

> **Error Code: 1418. This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled
>   (you
>   *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable).**

Y cuando intento ver si la función fue programada con éxito, lo hago así:

```
USE MODERN_FAMILY;
SELECT comparar_numeros(2,5);
```

Pero me tira este error:

> **Error Code: 2014. Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now**

Alguien sabe cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Gracias!!!

Answer (score 2):

Traducido de [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015160/deterministic-no-sql-or-reads-sql-data-in-its-declaration-and-binary-logging-i)

Hay dos formas de solucionar esto:

1. Ejecute lo siguiente en la consola de MySQL:

`SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;`

2. Agregue lo siguiente al archivo de configuración mysql.ini:

`log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;`

Para saber más te recomiendo leer la expliación original.

Answer (score 0):

El error es porque no has utilizado el `DETERMINISTIC`, tendrías que ponerlo en la siguiente línea:

```
RETURNS VARCHAR(20) DETERMINISTIC
```

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar, en la respuesta, por qué eso es necesario?. También puede ser buena idea dejar un link a la documentación oficial, para que el AP pueda entender por qué la necesita o qué otras opciones tiene. Para más información lee [answer]. Un saludo y bienvenido/a a StackOverflow

Comment: Las funciones deben llevar NOT DETERMINISTIC cuando los valores devueltos son de diferente tipo a los de ingreso. En este caso se reciben valores INT y se devuelve un VARCHAR.

Answer (score 0):

Resolví con la solución mas trivial: agregando la palabra `DETERMINISTIC` al `RETURNS` de mi función:

```
RETURNS decimal(7,2) DETERMINISTIC
```

Pd: Probé con `NOT DETERMINISTIC` ya que mi variable de entrada es `int` y la salida `decimal(7,2)` y no funcionó